# Retain focus on a UI element, but click a button on a different dialog. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I am developing a touchscreen friendly app that also includes a virtual keyboard. My virtual keyboard is in its own window, allowing it to be moved around. The problem is that when I click on a key on the keyboard the text box on the main application window no longer has focus. The switch from the main application being the active window to the keyboard dialog being the active window means that any field on the main window no longer has focus. How can I get around this?

I tried setting the keyboard window as not focusable. Though this is probably good to set, it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just return focus to the original window asynchronousely:

```
public static void BackgroundFocus(this UIElement el)    
{        
    Action a = () => el.Focus();        
    el.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, a);    
}
```

But this is not ideal, because the original window caption would flicker when losing focus...
Why don't you use [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function SetForegroundWindow() ,
I have used this long time back some where in my project 
May be this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Using a [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx), as already suggested, seems like a good solution. As for your custom window, try setting the [Window.ShowActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showactivated.aspx) to false.